# Git stage / git add

Tags: git, github-actions

Tengo problema con gits, en algunos archivos modificados no hace el stage desde VisualCode o agregarlos de forma general con git add . o **git add [Path]** de forma especifica, no muestra algún error o pista, al ejecutar **git status**, los archivos siguen en stage para el commit, la única forma de quitarlos de ahí es aplicando **git restore**.

Como dato curioso, solo son los que llevan un texto especifico en el archivo, ejemplo "Casas"

Comment: No entiendo. Si haces git add, normal que aparezcan en el stage para commit, no? que esperabas? Entenderia la pregunta si dijeras que haces add y no aparecen en el stage.

Comment: No se entiende lo que planteas. Por otra parte, qué tiene que ver esta pregunta con `github-actions`?

Comment: Lo solucione modificando el archivo config con ignorecase = false